# View Flipping in Android using same activity

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am new to android therefore I got a little bit lost with all those ViewFlipper, ViewSwitcher, ViewAnimator and ViewPager.  Moreover, I am not sure what's happening under the hood.

Basically I have an activity which shows some data. With swipe (or button, doesnt matter) I would like to scroll the view and get to another page (as seen in the picture below).

1. Is it possible to implement something like that without changing to another activity?
2. I am a little bit confused regarding views and access to the design elements. How those pages are located each to another? e.g. If I am currently seeing Page1, can I modify content of Page3? Or plainly saying, are all page views loaded all together? As if I set `setContentView(R.layout.xlayout);` then I can access only xlayout elements.
   But if I use same activity, then I have a thread there which updates a counter on Page1, if I change view to Page 2, the counter will not find Page1 Counter TextView and will complain.
3. As I Understand Android 4.0 has ViewPager which is similar to the seen in the picture. I am using GB. Should I use support library or can I just go around and implement something similar without importing any libraries?

(Sorry, my description is a little bit messy)

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use ViewSwitcher, ViewFlipper and ImageSwitcher depending on your requirements.

ViewSwitcher may have two childs at max. And these child might be a View or an object of subclass of view.

ViewFlipper: May have as many childs you want. and these child might be a View or an object of subclass of view.

ImageSwitcher might be used to switch images over.

By using view flipper you can display one item at a time, and adding a gesture overlay, you can apply sliding effect. To apply View Flipper, you need to add all the views to ViewFlipper, and showNext and showPrevious methods are used to show next and previous child.

Comment: So how about my 2. question. When I add views to the viewflipper. Can I access elements from all of them even though those views are not visible?

Comment: yes, you can, You can get any view from ViewFlipper by viewFlipper.getChildAt(int index) method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to have the same behaviour as in Google Play.
it only available on recent version of Android, but you can use the Compatibility Package to make it available for older version.

With a ViewFlipper you can't "scroll" between two pages.